# How to insert a SQL date-filtered query into another SQL query

Tags: sql, sorting, date

My goal is to have an output with dates only between Aug 17 to Aug 31. I was able to create a query that does that but the issue I'm having is how to insert it into an existing query without breaking it.

This is the working query that sorts the dates that I need:

```
SELECT *  FROM OUTING
WHERE OUT_DATE BETWEEN '27-AUG-16' AND '31-AUG-16';
```

And this is the code that I want to insert it into:

```
SELECT TOUR. TOUR_NAME, OUTING. OUT_DATE , 'Leaving: '||OUT_STARTLOC||' and 
Arriving: '||OUT_ENDLOC AS "LOCATIONS"
FROM OUTING JOIN TOUR ON OUTING.TOUR_ID = TOUR.TOUR_ID
ORDER BY OUT_DATE, TOUR_NAME
```

How would I be able to insert my sort by date query correctly?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to "insert" the first query into the second query? Do you just want to apply the same date filtering to the second query?

Comment: Just add the `where` clause after `from`? `FROM OUTING JOIN TOUR ON OUTING.TOUR_ID = TOUR.TOUR_ID WHERE OUT_DATE BETWEEN '27-AUG-16' AND '31-AUG-16'
ORDER BY OUT_DATE, TOUR_NAME`

Comment: Yes @CAW , I'd like to insert the date-filtered query into the second query. And Anthony Kong, that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Anthony Kong's comment, the following worked:

```
FROM OUTING JOIN TOUR ON OUTING.TOUR_ID = TOUR.TOUR_ID WHERE OUT_DATE BETWEEN 
'27-AUG-16' AND '31-AUG-16' ORDER BY OUT_DATE, TOUR_NAME
```